# How to remove an item instantly from the UI which is in a useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, use-state

I have a UI that you can add an item with a button that shows up instantly, and also, I need to remove it when you click on the trash icon. I store the items in a useState array, and since there is no unique id, I am using UUID to add each item with a unique id which supposes to help me identify it to delete when I need to.

here is the function to add item:

```
const [htmlArrayReg, setHtmlArrayReg] = useState([]);
enter code here
const addHtml = () => {

setHtmlArrayReg(htmlArray => [...htmlArray, <DateItem htmlArrayReg={htmlArrayReg} setHtmlArrayReg={setHtmlArrayReg} id={uuid()} />]);

}
```

I am printing the array to the UI as this:

```
<div>{htmlArrayReg && htmlArrayReg.map((elem) => elem)}</div>
```

With this function I am adding a DateItem item which is a component:

```
const DateItem = (props) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  const id = uuid();
 
  const onDelete = () => {
    props.setHtmlArrayReg(props.htmlArrayReg.map((item) => console.log(item.props.id) ));
  
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          margin: 20,
        }}
      >
        {props.word}
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <DatePickerWrapper
          popperContainer={Popper}
          calendarContainer={Calendar}
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        />
        <button
          className='btn btn-outline-primary'
          onClick={() => props.addHtml('and', props.kind)}
        >
          and
        </button>
        <button
          className='btn btn-outline-primary'
          onClick={() => props.addHtml('or', props.kind)}
        >
          or
        </button>
        <button
          className='btn btn-outline-primary'
          // style={{visibility:'hidden'}}
          onClick={onDelete}
        >
          <svg
            height='20px'
            id='Layer_1'
            style={{ enableBackground: 'new 0 0 512 512' }}
            version='1.1'
            viewBox='0 0 512 512'
            xmlSpace='preserve'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
          >
            <g>
              <path d='M413.7,133.4c-2.4-9-4-14-4-14c-2.6-9.3-9.2-9.3-19-10.9l-53.1-6.7c-6.6-1.1-6.6-1.1-9.2-6.8c-8.7-19.6-11.4-31-20.9-31   h-103c-9.5,0-12.1,11.4-20.8,31.1c-2.6,5.6-2.6,5.6-9.2,6.8l-53.2,6.7c-9.7,1.6-16.7,2.5-19.3,11.8c0,0-1.2,4.1-3.7,13   c-3.2,11.9-4.5,10.6,6.5,10.6h302.4C418.2,144.1,417,145.3,413.7,133.4z' />
              <path d='M379.4,176H132.6c-16.6,0-17.4,2.2-16.4,14.7l18.7,242.6c1.6,12.3,2.8,14.8,17.5,14.8h207.2c14.7,0,15.9-2.5,17.5-14.8   l18.7-242.6C396.8,178.1,396,176,379.4,176z' />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateItem;
```

I can add items easily, but I couldn't manage to create a proper delete function. Is there anybody to help me? It should delete instantly only the item I clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can store the id of new element in your state, so by clicking on the delete button you can find which item should be deleted based on the `id`, like this:

```
const [htmlArrayReg, setHtmlArrayReg] = useState([]);

 const deleteHtml = (elementId) => {
   setHtmlArrayReg(prevState => prevState.filter(({id})=> id !== elementId) )
 }

 const addHtml = () => {
   const id = uuid();
   setHtmlArrayReg(htmlArray => [...htmlArray, { id, elem:<DateItem id={id} onDelete={deleteHtml} /> } ]);
 }
```

now you can render your list like this:

```
<div>{htmlArrayReg && htmlArrayReg.map(({elem}) => elem)}</div>
```

and in the `DateItem` you can call the `onDelete` prop like this:

```
const DateItem = ({id, onDelete})=> {
  ...
  return (<>
    ...
    <button onClick={()=> onDelete(id)}>...</button>
  </>)
}
```